# How to prevent deletion of related data in Amplify Data

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I'm developing an app with react-native and amplify. I have amplify Data Model like below. As you can see, the BasketMenu model and Menu model have a relationship.

[amplify console Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z849U.png)

```
type BasketMenu @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  quantity: Int!
  Menu: Menu @hasOne
  basketID: ID! @index(name: "byBasket")
}

type Menu @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  category: MenuCategory!
  menuId: String
  menuName: String!
  menuType: MenuType!
  price: Int!
  cost: Int
  imageKey: String
  carts: [Cart] @manyToMany(relationName: "CartMenu")
  unit: Unit
  description: String
  note: String
  manufacturerID: ID! @index(name: "byManufacturer")
}
```

If I delete the BasketMenu's record, the related Menu will also be deleted. Is there a way to delete only the BasketMenu?

I deleted the BasketMenu and was expecting only the BasketMenu to be deleted, but the Menu was also deleted.